# FlexSlider, Media Galleries, & Nodes (entity reference)

Tags: nodes, media, javascript

If this has been asked before I apologize.

I'm somewhat new to Drupal but I know enough to dig myself a hole trying to find a solution to an idea.

I would like to use entity reference to display a media gallery and have the gallery formatted as a FlexSlider with thumbnail navigation.

I have tried both Flexslider Fields and FlexSlider Entity Reference but I can't seem to get either to work properly with Media Galleries.

Any suggestions?

I need it to be a simple interface a non-tech content creator can use without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the ”Entity Reference Views Formatter" module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_views_formatter

You then have full flexibility of views to output your Entity reference fields!

Here is a good thread on how to use the Entity reference views formatter module, setting up the correct Relationship and Argument can be a bit tricky.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1889358